# Foundation 5: tabs callback

Tags: zurb-foundation

Upgrading to Foundation 5. How do I add a callback to my tabs?

Looking at the code it doesn't seem to be possible.
It used to be cossible with Sections in Foundation 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They say there are two ways for callbacks
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tabs.html#callbacks

```
  $(document).foundation({
    tab: {
      callback : function (tab) {
        console.log(tab);
      }
    }
  });
```

and

```
$('#myTabs').on('toggled', function (event, tab) {
    console.log(tab);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, Christialt! I forgot to post back here, this issue was resolved a month ago. I submitted it back then to their Github and they've resolved it: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3690