# linking to a zurb foundation active accordion from external page

Tags: zurb-foundation, accordion

Trying to link to a page containing multiple accordion drop downs and I would like the link from an external page to navigate and activate the accordion. The normal :

```
<a href="blah.html#IDX">
```

will not work because it does not activate the accordion, it just navigates to the page. The code for the accordions is as follows:

```
<dl class="accordion accorborder" data-accordion>
    <dd class="accordion-navigation">
        <a href="#p1">Link Here</a>
        <div id="p1" class="content">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="small-6 columns">

               </div>
               <div class="small-6 columns">
```

What is the javascript that I will need to include or other modification to allow the code to work as intended?

Comment: This question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144978/foundation-5-tabs-callback. You need to use Foundaton's Tab Callback.