# Opening an Accordion via URL link (foundation v6.3.1)?

Tags: zurb-foundation, accordion

Is it possible to open a Foundation 6.3 accordion menu from a regular href link on the same page? I'm using the most current Foundation v6.3.1 and have found some info on doing this but nothing that works in my case.

This post seems to have an ideal solution ([Trigger opening of a Zurb Foundation Accordion via URL hash link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143266/trigger-opening-of-a-zurb-foundation-accordion-via-url-hash-link)) but it doesn't seem to jell with the latest release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, there are some alternative methods and the exact way it's applied is up to what you want to achieve, but basically the answer is: "use JavaScript".

This is my method:

1. Add a means of identifying the CONTENT of each tab you want to open. Below I have added a new data attribute (`data-remote`) to `.accordion-content`.
2. Create a link that has an id that corresponds to the new `data-remote` on the tab you want to open with that link. e.g. `id="toggleAco1"` & `data-remote="toggleAco1"`
3. Use the in-built Foundation function to toggle the tab on click (see JS/JQ below)

So all together it is something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="block">
  <ul class="accordion" data-accordion>
    <li class="accordion-item is-active" data-accordion-item>
      <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 1</a>
      <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content data-remote="toggleAco1">
        <p>Panel 1. Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        <a href="#">Nowhere to Go</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
      <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 2</a>
      <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content data-remote="toggleAco2">
        <textarea></textarea>
        <button class="button">I do nothing!</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
      <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 3</a>
      <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content data-remote="toggleAco3">
        Pick a date!
        <input type="date"></input>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <a href='#' class="button" id="toggleAco1">Open accordion tab 1</a>
  <a href='#' class="button" id="toggleAco2">Open accordion tab 2</a>
  <a href='#' class="button" id="toggleAco3">Open accordion tab 3</a>
</div>
```

**JS/JQ**

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    var dataTarget = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.accordion').foundation('toggle', $('[data-remote="' + dataTarget + '"]'));
});
```

- A [simple JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tymothytym/nw3wo5e3/1/)
- [The advanced options from the docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/accordion.html#javascript-reference)

N.B. What the links will do is linked to the [data attributes you include](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/accordion.html#advanced-options) and the same as if you clicked the accordion title for a tab. So if you allow multi-opening then the links will open each and leave it open, if you don't (as in the e.g.) then they will close once a new one is open etc.

Comment: This answer is fine.  You can also explicitly use the `up` and `down` events (instead of `toggle`).

Comment: This is a bit old now but I tried this with the responsive accordion/tab option and unfortunately, this does not seem to work with that setup. Is there another approach if using the responsive tabs?